# efi variables in yocto / qemu

Tags: yocto, qemu, uefi

I'm trying to test some stuff with regard to EFI variables in Qemu. I have my own distribution image built from Yocto SDK, but I don't know how to emulate UEFI and EFI variables (only for simulation in Qemu). I am using this to run Qemu:

```
runqemu qemux86 core-image-minimal nographic
```

Comment: Try `q35` and `OVMF`.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/140674a4601f804302e79d08cb06f91c882ddf28/OvmfPkg/README#L60) run the qemu with `-pflash path/to/OVMF.fd`